# How does EtherDelta work?

Tags: contract-development, ether, contract-invocation, exchanges, etherdelta

I'm still learning Solidity and contract development. I have never used EtherDelta. I know it can be used for trading different tokens, but I would like to understand the following two things:

How can new tokens be added ?

Can all ERC20 standard tokens be traded using EtherDelta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In this high level overview](https://etherboost.github.io/blog/etherdelta-smart-contract.html), the Etherboost team which is behind EtherDelta wrote:

> The EtherDelta smart contract allows you to deposit or withdraw Ether or any ERC-20 Ethereum token.

If you go to the [EtherDelta page](https://etherdelta.github.io), you can click on Tokens (in the top navigation bar) and see the list of all the tokens that are currently traded.

As to the process by which a new token gets listed on EtherDelta, I could not find any published information about what the steps are, so I would recommend getting in touch with them directly to ask. This really informative [Stemmit article here](https://steemit.com/ethereum/@profitgenerator/etherdelta-decentralized-token-exchange) about how to use EtherDelta lists several places you could ask that question:

> ...if you have any questions you can get in touch with them:
>   Chat: https://gitter.im/etherdelta/etherdelta.github.io 
>   Slack: https://slackin-etherboost.rhcloud.com 
>   Email: http://kontactr.com/user/etherboost 
>   Twitter: https://twitter.com/etherboost

**Later Edit:**

I emailed Etherboost to ask for clarification about how an ERC20 token gets listed on EtherDelta, and here is the answer I received:

> On Jul 19, 2017, at 4:01 PM, Zack Coburn wrote:
>
> 1. Any Ethereum-based token can be imported as a custom token and start trading on EtherDelta, without permission.
> 2. To appear on the list of official tokens, the token owner/creator should email etherboost@gmail.com with the following information:
>      a. Token address (code should be verified on Etherscan) b. Official
>      Web site (the token address should appear on the official Web site for
>      verification) c. Paragraph description of the token.
>
> Best, Zack