# Smart Contract with stable coin

Tags: ether, exchanges, tokens, stablecoins

Is there any stable coin, which can already be used with smart contracts?

If not, is there a possibility to exchange a stable coin in real time into a smart contract feasible coin like ETH by help with a smart contract? E.g.:

Tether -> ETH

and back

ETH -> Tether

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you could clarify your question. What is a *stable* coin? What do you want to do with it exactly? Do you speak about an ethereum token or about any crypto-coin? I do not know if it answers your questions but some tokens are traded on exchanges.

Comment: Stable coin = Tether, DAI, etc. I need to use a stable coin with a smart contract.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what is a stable price for you. What is stable in a stable coin? The coin itself (ie it will exist forever)? The price of the coin (USD Token)? The code of the coin? Something else?

If you want to use a token in a smart contract, you only have to call the functions of the contract. Hopefully, the token will be an ERC20 token so it will have some standard function to call.

Comment: Stable coin = Tether, DAI, etc. These are coins which are bound to one fiat currency (e.g. USD) or a fiat currency basket (e.g. EUR+USD+CYN)

Comment: "stable" is a very bad name for that. It is more a fixed price token.
But anyway you seem to know that such token exist, so why do you ask that ? Those tokens are tradable by smart contracts, see for example USDT. It is traded on some exchanges. You can also see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21583/how-does-etherdelta-work/21625#21625

Comment: On which Exchange is USDT traded by a smart contract? I can't find it on EtherDelta.

Answer (score 1):

Tether.to is building Ethereum(ERC20) based tether. Which is always begged back to real fiat deposit. 1 USD Tether is always equal to 1 USD. I think Every currency should follow the USDT and build fiat tether. I'm building Rupee tether. Advantages of ERC20 Tether is, we can use existing Ethereum smart contract platform. The potential is so huge.

[Recebt blog about ERC20 tether](https://tether.to/tether-ethfinex-collaborate-on-development-of-erc20-tether-tokens/)

Comment: Wouldn't that require to Ethereum itself, to send some currency other than ETH to the contract?  In the interim, what can we do?  Just create our own ERC-20 token and manage the trading between dollars that that token in a custom app?